# Why so many db hit in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

[image]
[image]
There is total 1 Category node and 2 Template node in my case. I put an * in [*] to support more further scenarios. But why there are so many db hit in this cypher for current data?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `*` in the relationship part of your query that's doing it.

While you've got only one Category node and two Template nodes, you've asked Neo4j to hop through any number of relationships to get from one to the other and not given it any help to narrow down the search besides specifying the starting node.

For example, if your Category was connected to 100,000 other nodes (of any label, not just Template) you've forced Neo4j to jump through every single one of them looking to see if there's a path to a Template node - and if those nodes have their own connections then they all need to be explored too, because the depth of the traversal isn't constrained.

If you know how Category and Template nodes can be connected in ways you're interested in (for example, if there's only every some specific set of relationships you want to traverse) then you'll radically improve the performance of the query. Equally, reducing the maximum length of the path will help.